Laravel 7 can not see videos in public storage
I have a project which contains some video files in storage/app/public/homepage/
The files are really there and in html there is something like
<video autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="http://localhost:8000/storage/homepage/vid3.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

But video does not play. I tried to run php artisan storage:link but it wrote

\public\storage] link already exists. The links have been created.

So I run php artisan serve but can not see the video on localhost. Network shows error 404 not found.
What am I doing wrong? Project is pretty old and everything worked till this day. I did not make any changes.
Thanks for help.

Is asset() helper function available in Laravel 7? If so perhaps try using that
<video autoplay muted> <source src="{{ asset('homepage/vid3.mp4')}}"></video>


<video autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="{{ asset('storage/homepage/vid3.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>

Explanation:

The base directory for the asset() helper function is the 'public' folder.
In the public folder, a 'storage' symlink is created and this symlink remains such that it points to 'storage/app/public'.
Therefore, if we were to use asset() to point to files on the public storage, we need to enclose ‘storage’ in the link.

